# Xamarin Cannot Implicityconvert type to xamarin.Forms.Page

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've just start new Xamarin.Forms project and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
In my App.cs file I'm trying to set my TestPage(I've created TestPage by Add->New Item-> BlankPage) as Main Page but i'm geting this error "Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'Paternity_Test.TestPage' to 'Xamarin.Forms.Page'"

My TesPage.xaml.cs

```
    namespace Paternity_Test
{

    public  partial class TestPage : Xamarin.Forms.Page
    {
        public TestPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

And My App.cs

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Paternity_Test
{
    public class App : Application
    {
        public App ()
        {
            MainPage = new TestPage();  //here Im geting this error

        }

        protected override void OnStart ()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep ()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume ()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What does your `.XAML` look like for that page? Just the top three lines will do

Comment: My Xaml :<Page
    x:Class="Paternity_Test.TestPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Paternity_Test"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Page x:Class="Paternity_Test.TestPage" xmlns="schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"; xmlns:x="schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"; xmlns:local="using:Paternity_Test" xmlns:d="schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"; xmlns:mc="schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"; mc:Ignorable="d">
```

You can not use those Microsoft XAML namespaces, they need to be Xamarin/ WinFx based:

- xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
- xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"

**FYI: You can not *currently* use `Blend` to create these XAML files**

### ContentView Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="TableHeaderBug.MyView">
    <ContentView.Content>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

### ContentPage Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="TableHeaderBug.MyPage99">
    <ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

[Xamarin.Forms XAML Basics](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/xaml-basics/)

[Part 1. Getting Started with XAML](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/xaml-basics/getting_started_with_xaml/)

> The first XML namespace declaration means that tags defined within the XAML file with no prefix refer to classes in Xamarin.Forms, for example ContentPage. The second namespace declaration defines a prefix of x. This is used for several elements and attributes that are intrinsic to XAML itself and which (in theory) are supported by all implementations of XAML. However, these elements and attributes are slightly different depending on the year embedded in the URI. **Xamarin.Forms supports the 2009 XAML specification, but not all of it**.

Answer (score 0):

Device.OnPlatform has been deprecated and the suggestion is to use switch(Device.RuntimePlatform)

Below is an example using the switch:

```
       switch(Device.RuntimePlatform)
        {
            case Device.iOS:
                Padding = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0);
                break;
            case Device.Android:
                Padding = new Thickness(10, 20, 0, 0);
                break;
            case Device.WinPhone:
                Padding = new Thickness(30, 20, 0, 0);
                break;
        }
```